# Tree Behavior gives lft and rght to null

Tags: php, tree, cakephp-4.x

I'm trying to use Tree Behavior in CakePHP4 on a table "rubriques" but each time I save an entry, both fields "lft" and "rght" have NULL value in my database...

**Database**

```
CREATE TABLE `rubriques` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `lft` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rght` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `slug` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Entity**

```
<?php

namespace App\Model\Entity;

use Cake\ORM\Entity;

class Rubrique extends Entity
{
    protected $_accessible = [
        '*' => true,
        'id' => false,
        'slug' => false
    ];
}
```

**Table**

```
<?php

namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;
use Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface;
use Cake\Event\Event;
use ArrayObject;
use Cake\Utility\Text;

class RubriquesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
        parent::initialize($config);
        $this->setTable('rubriques');
        $this->addBehavior('Tree');
    }

    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator): Validator
    {
        $validator
            ->notEmptyString('name');
            
        return $validator;
    }

}
```

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;


class RubriquesController extends AppController
{
    
    public function add(){
        $rubrique = $this->Rubriques->newEntity([
            'name' => 'Try',
            'parent_id' => null
        ]);
        
        $this->Rubriques->save($rubrique);

        die();
    }


}
```

The weird thing is when I rename my database table "rubriques" to "rubrics" (and change $this->setTable('rubrics') in my RubriquesTable, the fields "lft" and "rght" are correctly filled with values"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's seems I fixed the problem by deleting the files in tmp/cache/models/* and tmp/cache/persistent/*